# Flex: Draw on different frames of a MovieClip

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, movieclip, draw

How can I used ActionScript to draw on different frames of a movie clip. That is, make it so that movieClip.gotoAndStop(0); will show something different to movieClip.gotoAndStop(1);

Comment: A frame based system might not be the best solution for your problem if you are working in flex - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was wanting to do animation by loading each frame of the animation into a different frame of a movie clip.
I've since decided to write my own animation class using BitmapData etc.

Comment: Yep, that is probably a better approach.

Comment: As long as you don't want to also rotate the image along with the movie clip, I guess. Plain old blitting might not be enough for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use addFrameScript in your code.

For example, let's say you have a movieclip associated with the class CustomMovieClip.

In your CustomMovieClip's constructor, you can write something like the following (untested code):

class CustomMovieClip
{

...

function CustomMovieClip()
{
  stop();

// add drawGraphicsForFrame1 code into frame 0

addFrameScript(0, drawGraphicsForFrame1);

// add drawGraphicsForFrame2 code into frame 1

addFrameScript(1, drawGraphicsForFrame2);
  ...

}

private function drawGraphicsForFrame1():void
{
  stop();

var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
  addChildAt(sprite, 1);

// draw in sprite

sprite.graphics.lineStyle ...

}

private function drawGraphicsForFrame2():void
{

```
// remove the previous sprite (assumption: it's always at layer 1)

if (getChildAt(1) != null)
  removeChildAt(1);

 // draw new sprite

 var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
 addChildAt(sprite, 1);

 sprite.graphics.lineStyle ...
```

}

...